# Architecture of multi form project using c# WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, architecture, mdi

I´m about to develop a multi form project with let´s say ten forms. I want it to have a base frame which holds

- navigation controls and a menue structure
- small information section
- and main section where numerous forms will be displayed.

so its two or three smaller windows and one big window with the functional form.

The windows should be dockable and able to interact with the frame. Some windows might have parts that are not displayed for everyone (user no, admin yes). The forms should hold various data from an sql or oracle server.

Which techniques would you use to get everything synchronized?

Out of the blue I would use this structure to get the project working:

- MDI Application with a docking extension (developer express for example)
- User Controls if the Mainframe itself has "dynamic" fields to display
- Own Navigation class (which holds a history of opened forms)
- Global Connection Class which queues connection to databse
- MVC pattern for data handling with the help of the queue class

How can the forms interact with the frame?
I thought of using

- interfaces and inheritance (every form must have getData, navigateNext etcetc. function that gets called by the frame)
- linking varaibles (Childform -> Frame | Frame -> ChildForm) so the form can easily interact

is there a tutorial for something like this out there? (I found tutorials for the different techniques but don`t know if they will work together)

has anyone suggestions / additions?

Comment: MDI usually has wasteful submenues on all forms and that make it so..90. (or 80s). for dockability:  _maybe_ [this](http://dockpanelsuite.com/) is interesting.. Looks like nor forms but Panels.. Is using Winforms a given?

Comment: `I´m about to develop...` - using winforms for new  projects is unadvised. It's a legacy technology.

Comment: Indeed. Almost 20% of all new projects are built using WPF.. So much for advice.

Comment: have a look [here](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_controls/custom/article.php/c14179/Creating-a-Dockable-PanelControlmanager-Using-C-Part-1.htm)

Comment: thx for the answers. WinForm is a "must", yes. I think I´ll get the docking thing to work (with User Controls, with the DockPanel Suite or with our Developer Express extension which looks also promising - thx for the links)

Dies anyone have a good concept of the communication layer (frame <-> forms      |     menue <-> forms)?